# Session disappear if using automatic anonymous users

Tags: objective-c, session, parse-platform

I'm using next code to maintain automatic users for my app:

```
[Parse setApplicationId:@"XXX" clientKey:@"XXX"];

[PFUser enableAutomaticUser];

[[PFUser currentUser] saveInBackground];
```

After first launch I can see new user created and new session for it and all working OK. But after couple of additional launches session automatically disappear from dashboard and I always get :

> "...invalid session token (Code: 209, Version: 1.7.0)..." error.

If I log-out I will lost all user info, so this it not a good way for me.
How to use automatic users and new parse sessions?

PS. I testing this on Emulator.